# What is different between power off via power button, and via menu?

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

While trying to find an answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/938126/win-8-1-shutdown-delayed-exactly-5mins-without-any-logs) it became clear that Windows 8.1 shuts down differently depending on whether we pressed the power button (causing an issue in our case) or via the menu (from desktop, right click on "start" window logo at bottom left, select shutdown from the "shut down or sign out" popup menu... leads to a "normal" shutdown).

Is there a reason for this difference? Should there even be a difference?

Comment: Windows 8.1 by default uses a hybrid shutdown.  PC is turned off by start-up is faster.  Where as holding the power button forces the computer to be turned off entirely.

Comment: @Ramhound I think he might be looking for the difference between a Start Menu shutdown and the power option that governs 'what happens when you press the power button.' Not so much force powering off the computer.

Comment: and there should be no differance there? between the os getting a flag from the hardware or from the user entering  shut-down at the gui, they both should be the same.  All based on the shut-down being selected in the power options, as the thing to do when that button is pressed (for less than the 4-5seconds)

Comment: Note - I'm not talking about "holding down" the power button for a few seconds. Just a brief press to initiate shutdown... which (test after test has confirmed) behaves differently to invoking shutdown via the  menus described. Both "should be" the same, but consistently  aren't on 4 sets of more or less identical hardware when a certain GigE camera package is installed.

Comment: And why the downvote? This is a real phenomenon costing us valuable support time (shutdown via switch preferred, but leads to 5min delay due to faulty third party software...)

Comment: It is likely caused by creating a new question for the same basic problem.  It is better to fully update your original question, by editing it

Comment: That's disappointing. I personally see them as distinct queestions, although the question asked here is (now that I have found it) more or less a duplicate of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/598906/difference-between-software-initiated-shutdown-and-using-the-power-button?rq=1)... however that question cannot explain the difference observed here.